# ng2-bootstrap module in visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to import ng2-bootstrap module in VS project.
I fetch this github [repo](https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart) and it start successfully after adding `"moment": "2.11.2"` to `tsconfig.json`.

In VS I do almost the same, adding `"ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.5", "moment": "2.11.2"` to `tsconfig.json`, VS restoring it to `Dependencies`. Then with `gulp` I move `ng2-bootstrap.min.js, moment.js` to root app directory and bundle it to `index.html` and `moment.js` map in system.js configuration as `map: { moment: 'libs/moment.js }`.

After adding Alert component to my angular `class`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import {Router}       from 'angular2/router'
import {HeroService}  from './hero.service'
import {User}         from './user'
import {Alert}        from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap'

//declare var jwt_decode: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'app/login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/login.component.css', 'app/css/bootstrap.css',   'app/css/styles.css'],
    directives: [Alert]
})
```

After build I take a following error:

```
Error   TS2307  Build: Cannot find module 'moment'. ASPAngular2Test     E:\Development\C#\ASP.NET\ASPAngular2Test\src\ASPAngular2Test\node_modules\ng2-bootstrap\components\datepicker\date-formatter.ts    1
```

I insert this `<script src="libs/moment.js"></script>` into my `index.html`
and declare a variable in `date-formatter.ts` like `declare var moment: any`, error is gone, but after bulding bootstrap `tags` has no effect.

[Project Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG2u8.png)

And in mysterious way i get compiled `node_modules/ng2-bootstrap` and my all `ts` files in `wwwroot/app/scripts` directory. I replaced compiled `js` files in `wwwroot/app/`and it's also has no effect. My application don't see native properties of `ng2-bootstrap` components. Maybe someone faced with this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

you are adding ng2-bootstrap to tsconfig.json?

Shouldn't it be added to package.json?